# Можно ли bootstrap-reboot.min.css или normalize.css пропускать через gulp сборку?

Tags: bootstrap, gulp

Можно ли bootstrap-reboot.min.css или normalize.css пропускать через  эту gulp сборку?
Изначально я не могу bootstrap-reboot.min.css или normalize.css добавить в релизную папку, тк gulp сборка сносит ее и пересобирает заново при запуске gulp
Вот что будет gulp делать с bootstrap-reboot.min.css или normalize.css

```
    return src(path.src.css, {base: srcPath + "assets/scss/"})
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler : function(err) {
                notify.onError({
                    title:    "SCSS Error",
                    message:  "Error: <%= error.message %>"
                })(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cssbeautify())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(cssnano({
            zindex: false,
            discardComments: {
                removeAll: true
            }
        }))
        .pipe(removeComments())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min",
            extname: ".css"
        }))
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
} 



Пути к файлам (если нужно)

/* Paths */
const srcPath = "src/"
const distPath = "dist/"


const path = {
    build: {
        html: distPath,
        css: distPath + "assets/css/",
        js: distPath + "assets/js/",
        images: distPath + "assets/img/",
        fonts: distPath + "assets/fonts/"
    },
    src: {
        html: srcPath + "*.html",
        css: srcPath + "assets/scss/*.+(scss|css)", //change:sass/scss//
        js: srcPath + "assets/js/*.js",
        images: srcPath + "assets/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp,webmanifest,xml,json}",
        fonts:  srcPath + "assets/fonts/**/*.{css,eot,woff,woff2,ttf,svg}"
    },
    watch: {
        html:   srcPath + "**/*.html",
        js:     srcPath + "assets/js/**/*.js",
        css:    srcPath + "assets/scss/**/*.+(scss|css)", //change:sass/scss//
        images: srcPath + "assets/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp,webmanifest,xml,json}",
        fonts:  srcPath + "assets/fonts/**/*.{css,eot,woff,woff2,ttf,svg}"
    },
    clean: "./" + distPath
}



[![И собственно я попробовал это сделать но вот ошибки))Критичны ли?][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsvD9.png
```